# How do i make web application multilingual? (ReactJS, Flux, NodeJS, Postgres)

Tags: node.js, web-applications, reactjs, internationalization, multilingual

Ideally, i would like it to work like that:

- client's browser makes request to server,
- server identifies language based on request headers and sends specific language file along with js bundle and other assets

Only one language should be sent, because the webapp has quite lots of text.

How do I implement this?

Comment: Is there nothing useful coming up when Googling e.g. `node.js internationalization`?

Comment: ReactJS requires to render webapp on client side as well as on server side, so the question is a bit more complicated, than it seems to be

Answer (score 0):

I believe you answer is more theoretical? Several scenarios I can imagine here to try:

1. Load english by default. Then allow users to change language manually. Or show popup to select language right when page loads.
2. Serve templates from node, and in this case you will know which template to respond. Lets say client just requesting index.html or index.js This case server returns file with already correct language. But be careful with cache. Do same thing in react.
3. Not sure about react but in angular you do in templates {{ ctrl.text.helloText }}. Later in controller you load file by ajax with needed language. And populate ctrl.text with response. And angular rerenders these pieces. Until response come the will be empty text on the page. Hopefully if it will take less than 100~200 ms to get text file then it will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how we do it:

User identifies the language and it gets stored to user profile. On web app initialization client loads application code + localization dictionary(in our case plain JSON file). 
On the client-side, any strings that you show to user go through some function that translates the string.
e.g.  `_('Welcome!')`

And the dictionary looks something like this:

```
//spanish.json
{
  "Welcome!": "Bienvenido!",
  ...
}
```

Then it's just the matter of fetching the required dictionary on initialization and using translate function instead of hardcoded strings.